# Online Exam Project using Angular and WebAPI

Tags: html, css, angular

I am doing Online Exam Project using Angular and WebAPI. In Parent Component I am looping the buttons in the parent component equal to the no of count of questions. By clicking each button it will emit question and options respect to the question number displayed on the button. In child component I am displaying the question.

I click an option for 1st question and move to 2nd question and select option for 2nd question.
If I comeback to 1st question the selected is gone!!!
While, every time I go to the question, the previously selected option is unchecked, Since I looped the options in radio button!

PARENT COMPONENT

```
<div *ngFor ="let tests of test" style="align-items: center; float: left;">

     <button class="btn btn-info" (click)="OnClick(testtype,tests.Sno,tests.Qno)">{{tests.Qno}}</button> &nbsp;

</div>

<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
<div>
<label>{{test.Qno}}.{{test.Question}}</label>

<ng-container > 
    <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" class="example-radio-group"><br>
        <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let option of test.Options" (click)="Onclick(test.Qno,option)" [value]="option">
            {{option}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</mat-radio-button>
            <br/>
    </mat-radio-group>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to implements this is to use an array. The size of the array should be the number of questions selected.

Next, you may store the value selected or the index of the selected option.

To implement this, you have to check for change in selected value (answer) and on change, the value has to be updated to the array.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedObj" (change)="updateArray($event)">

<option *ngFor="obj of options" [ngValue]="obj">
    {{obj.name}}
</option>
</select>
```

If you need to view the previous questions selected option you may pick the answer from the array.